# Android USB Accessory Communication Does not Work (anymore) with Android kernel 3.18

Tags: android, usb, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an Android application that communicates with a custom hardware through that acts as an USB accessory. The software and the device communication works just fine with Android 6.0.1 with kernel versio 3.10 (SM-T555) but fails with Android 6.0.1 with kernel version 3.18 (SM-T580). The application detects the USB device, but and grants access to it, but no data is ever transmitted.

I noticed that the USB Configuration keeps on "Charging" on the newer Android device. Could this have some effect?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have to wrap the FileInputStream into BufferedInputStream for the reading to work.